# Disable Specific Categories By ID with wp_dropdown_cats WordPress Filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I use front-end form to allow users submit the posts from the front end.
I use this function `wp_dropdown_categories()` to allow users select which category the post will be in from a dropdown menu.
I use JaveScript to disallow users from selecting specific categories by disable these categories.
I want to **disable** (**not remove or exclude**) these categories with php where the user can see the category but he/she can't choose it.So my research reaches to this filter.
**So how can I use `wp_dropdown_cats` wordpress filter to disable specific categories by ID?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone need help in this problem the solution  [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-specific-categories-by-id-with-wp_dropdown_cats-wordpress-filter?replies=9)!

Answer (score 0):

This best option would to be use jQuery. Something like this would work:

```
$("select option:contains('VALUE HERE')").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I already use jQuery to do this job but I also want to do it with php for users whom have disabled JaveScript.